# MetalLB assigns IP to nginx, but Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: networking, kubernetes, k3s

I can't reach the IP address assigned (`192.168.0.240`) from outside the cluster.

```
❯ kubectl get services  -n kube-system -l app=nginx-ingress -o wide
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE    SELECTOR
nginx-ingress-controller   LoadBalancer   10.43.225.204   192.168.0.240   80:31012/TCP,443:32713/TCP   2d2h   app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=nginx-ingress
```

From a cluster node:

```
[sseneca@alarm-master ~]$ curl http://192.168.0.240/
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.8</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But from a machine on the network but not a part of the cluster:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.240 port 80: No route to host
```

And using `ping`:

```
❯ ping 192.168.0.240
PING 192.168.0.240 (192.168.0.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.21 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.21 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.21 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.240 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3095ms
pipe 3
```

I don't know how to debug this issue, any help appreciated. Somebody had a [suggestion](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/ingress-controllers-external-ip-cannot-be-reached/10086/2) on another forum but I didn't understand what they wanted me to do.

Comment: Try `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Comment: @Crou what does that command do?

Comment: `-P` stands for `Policy`, `FORWARD` is for packets that are neither emitted by the host nor directed to the host. They are the packets that the host is merely routing and `ACCEPT` is to accept that kind of traffic. This was mentioned as a solution [here](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/issues/1003).

Comment: @Crou doing `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` on all nodes and immediately testing, it doesn't seem to have worked. Am I meant to restart the nodes/a pod/etc.?

Comment: Can you share the steps how you deployed the cluster with all the deployed items, I will try to recreate the issue.

Comment: I'm primarily following [this guide](https://kauri.io/install-and-configure-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-k3s-to-self-host-applications/418b3bc1e0544fbc955a4bbba6fff8a9/a).  `metallb` and `nginx` are installed via the `helm` commands from the linked post.

Comment: Any luck maybe with this? Have the same issue

Comment: @seneca Do you still have this problem ?
Are you using `Raspbian Linux Operating System` and `Raspberry Pi` ?

Comment: did you resolve it? im in the same boat, heres my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67083713/metallb-works-only-in-master-node-cant-reach-ip-assigned-from-workers

Comment: Assuming it's L2, did you try `arping -c 5 192.168.0.240`?

Comment: Have you tried curl http://192.168.0.240:31012 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see installation documentation of metalLB.

You can achieve this by editing kube-proxy config in current cluster:

kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy

and set:

```
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: "ipvs"
ipvs:
  strictARP: true
```

You can not ping metalLB IP. But you can reach to service (port) from network.